# How do I change the main page of my quarto website

Tags: html, quarto

it's always redirecting to the about page

```
project: 
  type: website

website: 
  title: "Kansas Economic Data"
  page-footer:
    background: dark
    left: 
      - text: "GitHub Repo"
        url: "https://github.com/wsuppmc/driving-adoption-metrics"
    center:
      - text: "&trade;"

  navbar: 
    background: dark
    search: true
    right: 
      - text: "Home"
        file: Quartopage.qmd
      - about.qmd
  

format: 
  html:
    embed-resources: true
    page-layout: full
    toc: false
    css: styles.css
    footer: footer.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go to your _site folder in Rstudio, you'll find a bunch of html pages, click on index.html open it in the editor, change the URL to the new page you want to change to

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way was to rename the page I wanted as the homepage to `index.qmd`, as discussed [here on GitHub](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3530).